# Как выровнять форму по центру bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть на картинка на которую нужно наложить форму и выровнять по центру.
[image: Форма слева в углу нужно выровнять её по горизонтали и вертикали]

```
    `<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="img-wrap">  
    <img class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0;padding: 0px;" src="img/bgform.jpg">
    <img src="img/sale.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" id="sale">
    <form id="form" role="form" action="" method="post" class="center-block">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-3 text-center">
            <div class="control-group required">
                <div class="controls" style="margin-bottom: 10px">     
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя" id="name" maxlength="30" name="username" type="text" />
                </div>
                <div class="controls" style="margin-bottom: 10px">     
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Введите Ваш телефон" id="phone" maxlength="30" name="username" type="text" />
                </div>
                <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" class="button" value="Отправить"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>`
```

СSS:

```
.img-wrap {
  position: relative;
  color:#ffc000;[![Форма в углу нужно центрировать её по вертикали и горизонтали][1]][1]
}

.img-wrap h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 1%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.img-wrap #sale {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 1%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}
.img-wrap #form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 1%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

```css
#form {
  max-width: 250px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form id="form" role="form" action="" method="post" class="center-block">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group text-center">
      <div class="control-group required">
        <div class="controls" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя" id="name" maxlength="30" name="username" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="controls" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Введите Ваш телефон" id="phone" maxlength="30" name="username" type="text" />
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" class="button" value="Отправить" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Мне нужно именно поверх картинки. Так всё правильно но при задании position:absolute форма сдвигается влево. Position:absolute необходимо для помещения поверх картинки. Что можно сделать в этом случае?

Comment: @Alexandr - фоновое изображение задайте для img-wrap

Comment: это изображение будет адаптивным?

Comment: @Alexandr - да, добавив background-size: cover

Comment: изображение обрезалось по высоте. Как исправить подскажите , пожалуйста

Comment: @Alexandr - min-height: XXpx - поставить нужное значение

Comment: Спасибо, помогло